# How to clone a domain connected PC to another machine

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, iso-image

I was given a PC at work that's configured for the company's domain and VPN with Windows 10.

I prefer using Linux, so using UEFI I shrunk the Windows partition and installed Linux along side and works like a charm.

However many services are behind the VPN that I can't access from Linux since it's blocked at the Org level.  Switching back and forth is not cutting it anymore!

I have a spare laptop and I was wondering if there's a way to image Windows 10 into a bootable ISO that I can load onto the other laptop while saving the domain config?

Linux has a way to create a complete ISO with data/configs.  Does Windows or any third party software do the same?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Windows 10 Enterprise.. Read up on Windows To Go

Comment: Would you like me to post that as an answer or would you like to continue and see if it works before I post it as an answer?

Comment: @varfirstName It looks like I can use Windows To Go to install Windows and run it off a USB drive, but I am looking for an ISO I can install on the second laptop